# Why does compiling the Linux kernel cause Ubuntu to freeze?

Tags: compiling, make

I need help figuring out how compiling the Linux kernel causes Ubuntu to freeze.

I'm trying to cross-compile the Linux kernel for the ZedBoard. It is a Zynq-7000 ARM architecture. When I compile, it gets down to a `journal.o` file and the entire system freezes and I have to restart. Xilinx/ZedBoard has no idea, so maybe somebody else does. Let me know what other information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the man page for make with `$ man make`, it explains a little more. The `-j` flag, when followed by a number, restricts the number of processes running at one time to whatever you put. However, if `-j` is not followed by a number, the number of threads is not limited. I think since it was executing so many threads at one time, it hosed things up. As soon as I used `make ARCH=arm UIMAGE_LOADADDR=0x8000 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi- uImage`, everything worked; granted, it was slow, but it worked. Perhaps you could add a `-j 10` or something to make things run a little faster without overloading the OS.

Comment: Not to mention the Xilinx cross-compile tools must be used

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue when compiling the kernel for zynq.
This is what I used:
make -j ARCH=arm UIMAGE_LOADADDR=0x8000 uImage

Now I change it into:
make ARCH=arm

and it compiles and creates the Image and zImage in the \arch\arm\boot\

Goodluck

Comment: I found the same thing. Explanation below!